# add prototype for the second function in c programming

Tags: c

I have two functions that call each other. The book (p147, All of Programming, Andrew Hilton, Anne Bracy) says we need to write the prototype for the second function before the first to let the compiler know about the existence of the second function. My question is when we call `isOdd` and `isEven` in `main`, which is at the bottom of the file, has the compiler already known `isOdd` and `isEven` if the compiler reads the file from the beginning to the end?

```
int isOdd(unsigned int n); // do we need this and why?

int isEven(unsigned int n) {
   // return whether the input is even
   // call isOdd
}

int isOdd(unsigned int n) {
  // return whether the input is odd
  // call isEven
}

int main(void) {
  // call isOdd and isEven
}
```

Comment: There's the line `// call isOdd` inside `isEven()`; that's why you need the prototype.

Comment: Does https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-pass_compiler help?

Comment: You need to differentiate between "compile time" and "run time". When compiling, the source is read sequentially, and each (user defined) reference has to be declared before. In contrary, at run time the sequence of calls can be totally different.

Answer (score 0):

You only need it because `isEven` calls `isOdd`.  At that point in the code, the compiler needs to know what `isOdd` is.  If only `main` called `isOdd` then you wouldn't need the declaration at the top.

Comment: The execution of the program starts from `main`. In `main`, when we call `isEven`, has the complier already known `isOdd`? Do you mean that when the compiler reads `isEven` and `isEven` calls `isOdd` so the compiler needs to know what `isOdd` is? But the `main` hasn't called `isEven` that `isEven` hasn't been executed?

Comment: But the compiler has to read your file first.  When it encounters the call to `isOdd` inside of `isEven`, it has to know what you're talking about.  It doesn't need to have the function definition yet.  It merely needs to know what kind of arguments the function takes and what it returns.

Comment: Trying compiling this file: `int main() { printf("Hello!\n"); return 0; }\n#include <stdio.h>`
See what warning it gives you.